# How to convert Graphics2D to BufferedImage?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have graphics course on my study. My current task is to draw a hex using Bresenham algorithm and flood fill it using stack-based recursive algorithm. So I need the color of a contour to use flood filling.

The code below draws lines using `Graphics2D`, and I need to get color of each drew pixel. As I understand, `Graphics2D` is an abstraction which doesn't contain pixels. So I need to convert the hex to `BufferedImage`, use `.getRGB()` method and get the color of the pixel. But I can't make head or tail of it.

How can I make the `BufferedImage` of a hex drew with the `Graphics2D`?

```
public void drawHexagon(int x, int y, int edgeLength, int thickness, Graphics2D g2d) {
    int cosEdgeLength = (int) (Math.cos(Math.PI / 6) * edgeLength);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(edgeLength*2, cosEdgeLength*2 + edgeLength, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    drawBresenhamLine(x, y, x - edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength, g2d, thickness);
    drawBresenhamLine(x, y, x + edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength, g2d, thickness);
    drawBresenhamLine(x - edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength, x - edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength + edgeLength, g2d, thickness);
    drawBresenhamLine(x + edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength, x + edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength + edgeLength, g2d, thickness);
    drawBresenhamLine(x + edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength + edgeLength, x, y + cosEdgeLength + edgeLength + cosEdgeLength, g2d, thickness);
    drawBresenhamLine(x - edgeLength, y + cosEdgeLength + edgeLength, x, y + cosEdgeLength + edgeLength + cosEdgeLength, g2d, thickness);
    g2d.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
}

void drawBresenhamLine (double xstart, double ystart, double xend, double yend, Graphics2D g, int thickness)
{
    double x, y, dx, dy, incx, incy, pdx, pdy, es, el, err;
    dx = xend - xstart;
    dy = yend - ystart;
    incx = sign(dx);
    incy = sign(dy);
    if (dx < 0) dx = -dx;
    if (dy < 0) dy = -dy;
    if (dx > dy) {
        pdx = incx; pdy = 0;
        es = dy;    el = dx;
    } else {
        pdx = 0;    pdy = incy;
        es = dx;    el = dy;
    }
    x = xstart;
    y = ystart;
    err = el/2;
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
    g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, y));
    for (int t = 0; t < el; t++) {
        err -= es;
        if (err < 0) {
            err += el;
            x += incx;
            y += incy;
        } else {
            x += pdx;
            y += pdy;
        }
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Drawing an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple, create a BufferedImage then draw on it

```
    int width = 500; // example value
    int height = 500; // example value
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
```

use this graphics in your:

```
drawHexagon(int x, int y, int edgeLength, int thickness, Graphics2D g2d)
```

after execution you will have the drawing on this BufferedImage

Comment: Consider using `createGraphics` over `getGraphics`, as it returns a `Graphics2D` (so no casting) and `getGraphics` is provided for backwards compatibility

Comment: *"that is a good hint"* An [edit to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35861776/edit) would be better.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw on a BufferedImage instead of drawing on the panel, get the Graphics property from the BufferedImage and draw on it:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel{    
    private BufferedImage buf;   

    public DrawingSpace(){            
        //Initialization of variables and dimensions not shown
        buf = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }

    public void drawOnBuffer(){
        Graphics g2d = buf.createGraphics();
        g2d .setColor(Color.BLUE);    //draw the things you want
        g2d .fillOval(0,0,200,200);   //draw the things you want
        g2d .dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `extends JPanel` there is no need for that. When it comes to displaying the image, it is easier to use a `JLabel` with an icon.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was conveying the idea if he uses JPanel for custom drawing, he can still use Graphics to draw else where (such as on BufferedImage and not necessarily on JPanel).

Comment: Your example throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` when invoking `createGraphics()`.

Comment: Thanks to all who pointed out the mistakes in my post. It has been edited.